# Looking for a regular expression to validate 10 digit numbers on separate line

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to validate user entered values which

```
a. Starts with 2
b. 10 digit in length
c. could be multiple numbers separated by new line
```

example.

```
2123123123 - Valid

2123123123
2987654321 - Valid

2123123123
newline    - Invalid
```

I am using expression as `"^[2]\d{9}(?:\r\n[2]\d{9})*$"`. it works only if I enter one 10 digit number but not working for multiple numbers on newline

Comment: Your regex is almost ok, try `"\A2[0-9]{9}(?:\r\n2[0-9]{9})*\z"`. Does it work as expected?

Comment: Do I get you right that the only trouble is when your string of 10 digit lines ends with a newline (LF) symbol?

Comment: Yes that is correct, it gives trouble when validating 10 digit numbers on newline with Carriage  Return and New line

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew - Expression you provided didn't work. It is not working for single 10 digit number. example - 2123123123

Comment: Look, [it matches that string](http://ideone.com/vNYHTC). See [more tests](http://ideone.com/yRkqmj) - isn't it doing what you need?

Comment: I've a user control textbox and using RegularExpressionValidator for it and setting ValidationExpression = "^[2]\d{9}(?:\r\n[2]\d{9})*$" however not working I was working earlier but seems broken after upgrading visual studio to 2015

Comment: Do you mean you pass the regex to the JavaScript engine to validate strings at the client side? Are you sure there is any `CR` at all there? Try `"^2[0-9]{9}(?:\r?\n2[0-9]{9})*$"`

Answer (score 0):

if you wan only to allow numbers separated by **one** new line, you can use this approach:

```
^2\d{9}(\r\n2\d{9})?$
```

but if you want to consider valid any number of lines, you have to switch to:

```
^2\d{9}(\r\n2\d{9})*$
```

## NOTE

I should admit `\r` optionally, to parse as valid `\r\n` or `\n` either.  If you need to consider also the possibility of having blank spaces around the numbers, you should consider:

```
^\s*2\d{9}(\s*\r?\n\s*2\d{9})*\s*$
```

the anchors `^` and `$` are neccessary or you can be accepting lines terminating in a sequence of ten digits beginning by `2` or having the sequence at the beginning of a line.

See this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/RMoskz/1) for the last regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Below one fixed my issue,

^[2]\d{9}(?:\r?\n[2]\d{9})*$

Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score -1):

That's my solution:

```
"^2\d{9}(\r\n2\d{9})*$"
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Is the solution i provided not working?